FastAPIをDocker経由で立ち上げたがどこにアクセスすればよいのかわからない
概要
FastAPIの勉強がてらDockerを使ってみています
Docker composeの立ち上げまではうまくいったのですが、http://127.0.0.1:8000/、http://localhost:8000/どちらも反応がありません。
FastAPI単体で起動してみたところ、http://127.0.0.1:8000/にアクセスできたので、Docker側の問題だと思います。
環境

Windows 11
PowerShell 7
Python 3.12
FastAPI 0.115
Docker Client 27.3.1
Docker Compose v2.30.3-desktop.1

C:.
├─.devcontainer
├─.github
├─.venv
└─app

Docker
ほぼdocker initとVSCodeのコマンドで生成したものです。
Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.13
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim AS base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/app" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser \
    && chown -R appuser:appuser /app

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--reload"]

compose.yaml
# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Docker compose reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-spec-reference/

# Here the instructions define your application as a service called "server".
# This service is built from the Dockerfile in the current directory.
# You can add other services your application may depend on here, such as a
# database or a cache. For examples, see the Awesome Compose repository:
# https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

# The commented out section below is an example of how to define a PostgreSQL
# database that your application can use. `depends_on` tells Docker Compose to
# start the database before your application. The `db-data` volume persists the
# database data between container restarts. The `db-password` secret is used
# to set the database password. You must create `db/password.txt` and add
# a password of your choosing to it before running `docker compose up`.
#     depends_on:
#       db:
#         condition: service_healthy
#   db:
#     image: postgres
#     restart: always
#     user: postgres
#     secrets:
#       - db-password
#     volumes:
#       - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
#     environment:
#       - POSTGRES_DB=example
#       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
#     expose:
#       - 5432
#     healthcheck:
#       test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
#       interval: 10s
#       timeout: 5s
#       retries: 5
# volumes:
#   db-data:
# secrets:
#   db-password:
#     file: db/password.txt

LOG
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container fastapi_practice-server-1  Recreated               0.2s 
Attaching to server-1
server-1  | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
server-1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
server-1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles                                                                               
to quit)
server-1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles
server-1  | INFO:     Started server process [8]
server-1  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
server-1  | INFO:     Application startup complete.


バインドについてよく理解していなかったことが原因でした。
バインドとは、ネットワークプログラミングにおいて、特定のネットワークインターフェースやポートに対してソケットを割り当て、接続を待ち受ける処理のことです。
具体的には、次のようなことを言います。

IPアドレスとポート番号を特定のアプリケーションやサービスに「結び付ける」こと
サーバーが特定のネットワークインターフェース上で接続を受け入れる準備をする処理

この事例では、外部からアプリにアクセスするためDocker Containerは0.0.0.0に設定されています。
同様に、uvicornも起動コマンドに--host 0.0.0.0を追加して、Docker Containerと合わせてやることで、アクセスが可能になりました。
また、一応port --8000を明示してやるとよいと思います。
